# Sum all numbers that start with the same first two digits for each name

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to write a script to sum all numbers (column 2) start with the same first two digits (column 1) and then save them with the same first two digits then zeros (i.e. 1001 will be 1000, 96542 will be 96000). For example;

```
ele  table  5
        1001.03c  1
        1002.03c  2
        1003.03c  1
        2003.03c  3
        2004.03c  1
        3006.03c  0
        3007.03c  5
       44009.03c  1
ele table  22  
        1001.03c  1
        1002.03c  0
        1003.03c  0.2
        2003.03c  1
        2004.03c  2
        3006.03c  2.2
        3007.03c  3
       44009.03c  0
       55010.03c  2
```

So, the idea is that to get an output file with following output:

```
    ele  table  5
        1000.03c  4
        2000.03c  4
        3000.03c  5
       44000.03c  1
ele table  22  
        1000.03c  1.2
        2000.03c  3
        3000.03c  5.2
        4000.03c  0
       55000.03c  2
```

That list goes for a long file. I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: What look your script now? Please post!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and add sample input and expected output. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Am working on it now, I will post it when finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'function pr(){ 
         printf "\t%d%0*d%s  %s\n", k, len-6, "", fr, sum; sum = 0;  
     }
     /^ele +table/{
         if (k) pr();
         print; next
     }
     k && substr($1, 1, 2) != k{ pr() }
     { 
         k = substr($1, 1, 2); 
         len = length($1);
         fr = substr($1, index($1, "."));
         sum += $2 
     }
     END{ pr() }' file
```

The output:

```
ele  table  5
    1000.03c  4
    2000.03c  4
    3000.03c  5
    44000.03c  1
ele table  22  
    44000.03c  0
    1000.03c  1.2
    2000.03c  3
    3000.03c  5.2
    44000.03c  0
    55000.03c  2
```